# Security of capabilities vs setuid (LD_PRELOAD, etc)

Tags: linux, security, setuid, capabilities, setcap

I know that if a process is run [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) that it's protected against various things that could subvert the process, like [LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick) and [ptrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace) (debugging). But I haven't been able to find anything on the same being done for [capabilities](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities). I *assume* the same sorts of things are done with capabilities, since otherwise it would have huge security holes, but I haven't been able to find it documented/verified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned [in this Kernel Mailing List message](https://lkml.org/lkml/2006/8/17/161), whether a process needs extra security is checked in [`cap_bprm_secureexec()` of the kernel file `security/commoncap.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/security/commoncap.c#L593), which does check for capabilities.  This is then exported to the process via the [auxiliary vector](http://articles.manugarg.com/aboutelfauxiliaryvectors.html).  This can be accessed/tested via [`getauxval(AT_SECURE)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getauxval.3.html).  I inserted `getauxval(AT_SECURE)` into a test program, and it did indeed return 1 when it was running with any capabilities set and usable, the same as it would if running setuid, so capabilities have the same security protections as setuid.